# Getting data from WP Query and into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to query a set of locations from a `location` post type from WordPress and then set those into a javascript array so I can use it with the Google Matrix API. I'm just not quite sure the best way to go about it overall.

I can construct the query, but then to run it over a loop, I'm not sure if I just jam a variable in somewhere to get the data out or how the best process for that would be.

This is what I'm trying to do so far:

```
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'locations', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
            $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
              <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
              $title = esc_html( get_the_title() );
              $location = get_field('address');
              ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<script>
var locations = <?php json_encode($the_data_im_trying_to_get) ?>;
//other JS things...
</script>
```

The other kicker is I'm also not sure merge in the ACF data along with the post type data too?

I was looking into `query_posts` a bit that *might* work, but then again, I'm not sure how to get all of the posts for that post type and get the ACF data out of that as well.

Again, not totally sure if I'm going about this the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      dataFromQuery  = "<?= base64_encode(json_encode($the_data_im_trying_to_get));?>";
</script>
```

You can try above code to get data in javascript array.

And to parse this array, you can use below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      temp = JSON.parse(atob(dataFromQuery));
</script>
```